# Pandas error when I try to do an Anova test

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, anova

so I have an excel sheet that I'm trying to do an ANOVA test on through pandas. It worked with several other spreadsheets, but with this one, using the exact same code, I get an error. Here's the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.formula.api import ols
import pingouin as pg
df = pd.read_excel('anovacogret.xlsx')
aov = pg.anova(data=df, dv='Cognitive Reattribution', between='Type', detailed=True)
aov
```

and the error I get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py:3621, in Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3620 try:
-> 3621     return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3622 except KeyError as err:

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/_libs/index.pyx:136, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/_libs/index.pyx:163, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi:5198, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

File pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi:5206, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'Cognitive Reattribution'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [1], in <cell line: 6>()
      4 import pingouin as pg
      5 df = pd.read_excel('anovacogret.xlsx')
----> 6 aov = pg.anova(data=df, dv='Cognitive Reattribution', between='Type', detailed=True)
      7 aov

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pingouin/parametric.py:926, in anova(data, dv, between, ss_type, detailed, effsize)
    923         return anovan(dv=dv, between=between, data=data, ss_type=ss_type, effsize=effsize)
    925 # Check data
--> 926 _check_dataframe(dv=dv, between=between, data=data, effects='between')
    928 # Drop missing values
    929 data = data[[dv, between]].dropna()

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pingouin/utils.py:330, in _check_dataframe(data, dv, between, within, subject, effects)
    328     raise ValueError('DV and data must be specified')
    329 # Check that dv is a numeric variable
--> 330 if data[dv].dtype.kind not in 'fi':
    331     raise ValueError('DV must be numeric.')
    332 # Check that effects is provided

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:3505, in DataFrame.__getitem__(self, key)
   3503 if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   3504     return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 3505 indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   3506 if is_integer(indexer):
   3507     indexer = [indexer]

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py:3623, in Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3621     return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3622 except KeyError as err:
-> 3623     raise KeyError(key) from err
   3624 except TypeError:
   3625     # If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise
   3626     #  InvalidIndexError. Otherwise we fall through and re-raise
   3627     #  the TypeError.
   3628     self._check_indexing_error(key)

KeyError: 'Cognitive Reattribution'
```

Can anyone help me figure this out? Thank you.

Comment: can you provide a sample of `df` as DataFrame constructor and the expected output?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.